# Changing SVG colors

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm starting to learn JS and i have this (probably very easy) task that I'm having problems with.
So the main task is to make the lower green triangle change it's color depending on which color i click on upper object.
I made something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>SVG, JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor("triangle"){
    document.getElementById("group").getAttributeNS("fill");
    evt.target.setAttributeNS("fill");
  }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <svg height="500" width="500"> 
        <g id="group">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" style="fill:gray;stroke:none;stroke-width:0"/>
            <rect id="red_triangle" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill:red;stroke:none;stroke-width:0"/>
            <rect id="yellow_triangle"x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill:yellow;stroke:none;stroke-width:0"/>
            <rect id="blue_triangle"x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:blue;stroke:none;stroke-width:0v"/>
            <rect id="green_triangle"x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;stroke-width:0"/>
            <ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx="100" ry="100" style="fill:gray;stroke:none;stroke-width:0"/>
            <polygon id="triangle" points="100,225 150,300 50,300" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;stroke-width:0" onclick="changeColor("triangle")"/>
        </g>
    </svg>


</body>
</html>
```

but obviously it's not working. Could somebody help me with some suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// the string instead of argument name raises Error: unexpected string
function changeColor("triangle"){ 

// you get the attribute but don't do anything with it.
// and the group doesn't even have a fill attribute
   document.getElementById("group").getAttributeNS("fill");

// here you try to set an attribute but setAttributeNS requires 3 arguments: namespace, attribute and value
// simpler setAttribute would be enough, but the value would still be overwriten by style="fill:whatever"
// and evt.target is undefined, there's no evt object
   evt.target.setAttributeNS("fill");
}
```

then in your SVG:

```
// the quotes are broken, 
// and here you pass a string which I'd assume to be the ID of an element you want to change
onclick="changeColor("triangle")"
```

So, all in all:

The onclick should be on the source rectangles, not the target triangle: `<rect onclick="changeColor('triangle', this)" />` where `'triangle'` is the ID of element you want to change, and `this` is a reference to the clicked rectangle.

**SVG:**

```
<svg height="500" width="500"> 
    <g id="group">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" style="fill:gray;stroke:none;stroke-width:0"/>
        <rect id="red_triangle" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill:red;stroke:none;stroke-width:0" onclick="changeColor('triangle', this)"/>
        <rect id="yellow_triangle"x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill:yellow;stroke:none;stroke-width:0" onclick="changeColor('triangle', this)"/>
        <rect id="blue_triangle"x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:blue;stroke:none;stroke-width:0v" onclick="changeColor('triangle', this)"/>
        <rect id="green_triangle"x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;stroke-width:0" onclick="changeColor('triangle', this)"/>
        <ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx="100" ry="100" style="fill:gray;stroke:none;stroke-width:0"/>
        <polygon id="triangle" points="100,225 150,300 50,300" style="fill:lime;stroke:none;stroke-width:0" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

**JS:**

```
function changeColor( target, source ){
    var color = source.style.fill;
    document.getElementById( target ).style["fill"] = color;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harg5kyz/1/